# How to extract selected data from interactive htmlwidget plot

Tags: r, shiny, htmlwidgets

I am trying to figure out a way to extract data from a selection of an interactive plot in Shiny. I build a parallel coordinates plot using a package found at https://github.com/timelyportfolio/parcoords which builds a parcoords chart using htmlWidgets. It allows users to make specific slections, as seen below:
[image][image]

What I need is a way to extract the highlighted rows from the underlying data set, either through a download button or data table. Is there anyway to pull out this info from the underlying htmlWidget process? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`crosstalk`](https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/) you can let one htmlwidget talk to another. The dev version of `parcoords` [supports](https://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/55a952fc329ffca428c412432d72049c) crosstalk integration as does `datatable`, so you can link the two with minimal effort

Comment: This has been helpful and works great for well defined plot functions, but I am trying to figure out how to do it for a custom html widget. I am havign a hard time figuring out how to set brush IDs which I can use to update the SharedData object. Thansk for pointing me in the right direction, though.

Comment: NVM, got it too work. The version you linked was very helpful.